# Increase Xmx and Xms for grails run-app

Tags: grails

We currently are having performance issues with grails. It is taking about 10 seconds to load one of our main pages. I checked and saw that our grails app was starting up with 512 memory. We currently can use up to 3.5 gigs worth of ram.

I tried exporting the following:

> export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024M -server"

After checking how it started up it seems as if it still started with the 512m setting. Where is this set?

Comment: Is your Grails app running in a servlet container, e.g. Tomcat, or are you using the grails run-app command?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

*Csaba*'s answer is not accurate.

You don't need to tweak the startGrails script. This is something dangerous since the next time you will upgrade Grails, you will lose your configuration. I am not even talking about an environment that should be the same among multiple developers!

The solution is quite simple :

1. Define `GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024M -server"`
2. Do not define `JAVA_OPTS`

Comment: except that in the windows startGrails.bat script, there is no GRAILS_OPTS!

Comment: @6006604 from the command line in Windows run `set GRAILS_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024M -server` then your usual `grails run-app`.  Use VirtualVM to convince yourself the settings are taking.

Comment: @fabien7474 I am having the same problem and I added this to my .bashrc file on ubuntu `export GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024M -server"` , but that did not help, I still get the same error, is there anything else I am missing here ?

Comment: what does the -server option does?

Comment: Also be aware that grails.project.fork in BuildConfig.groovy can override memory settings. Take a look at this answer on another post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23562774/311525

Answer (score 8):

I assume you use Linux or some other unix variant.

Unfortunately it seems that (at least in Grails 1.1.1) the `$GRAILS_HOME/bin/startGrails` directly set a `-Xmx512m` value in `JAVA_OPTS` (on Windows, the `startGrails.bat` only set this if you do not provide your own value - I wonder why the unix script behaves different). It seems that the only way currently is to override this setting in `startGrails`.

Note that the above only true for development. If you deploy a war to an application server the memory settings in the server startup script will be used.

**Update 2010.07.30**: as fabian7474 wrote, [from Grails 1.2.2](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5891) you can use `GRAILS_OPTS` to specify vm parameters and now it is the recommended way.