# New install of Grails 2.0.3 Ubuntu seemed fine, but running grails just returns after a few seconds

Tags: linux, grails, installation

I have just installed grails 2.0.3 on my Ubuntu box using apt-get as described here:

http://grails.org/Download

Everything looked fine.

When I type grails in the terminal it takes about 5 seconds and then it returns to the prompt without having done anything. No errors, no text.

I have tried adding GRAILS_HOME even though the download instructions say it is not required but that didn't help either.

It's finding grails just fine, it's just not doing anything.

I have not explicitly installed groovy before this. Is that a step I missed (I don't think so as I see it's included in the libs folder of the install)
 or is there more I need to do to finish the install?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I managed to solve it.

I have grails 2.1.2 installed in a Ubuntu, running in a VirtualBox instance, with 512MB of memory.

I had to install java 6 to run grails and configure `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, although grails documentation says it is not necessary.

According to several resources, it may be caused by a grails memory usage issue. It seems that grails uses a lot of memory or something similar. These resources are:

- Stack Overflow thread: [Grails application hogging too much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535458/grails-application-hogging-too-much-memory)
- [Grails deployment documentation](http://www.grails.org/Deployment)
- Stack Overflow thread: [Increase Xmx and Xms for grails run-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260645/increase-xmx-and-xms-for-grails-run-app)

So, following their advice, I configured an environment variable, GRAILS_OPTS with this command:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-server -Xms128M -Xmx128 -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
```

Try it out and tell us if it works for you, thanks.