# Could not reserve enough space for object heap in grails

Tags: grails, heap-memory

I am working on GGTS 3.5 and Grails version 2.3.7. When i run my project, we are facing an issue with Heap size.

```
Windows 7 32 bit; RAM: 3gb.
Java 1.7 .
```

I set below environment variables as well.

```
GRAILS_OPTS = -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024m -server
JAVA_OPTS = -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024m -server
```

and changed my `GRAILS_OPTS` in start grails file. But still facing the same issue.

I have just started working in java and grails, please help me out. Many thanks in advance.
Error Desc:

```
Loading Grails 2.3.7 
Configuring classpath . 
Environment set to development ................................. 
Packaging Grails application .......................................... 
Running Grails
application Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
Error occurred during initialization of VM 
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error | Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to change memory parameters in your BuildConfig

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

Comment: I tweaked memory parameters but still was facing the issue. I was suggested to upgrade my machine configuration to 8gig ram. when i upgraded, i wasn't getting the error. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you! I have spent so much time trying to figure out why GRAILS_OPTS weren't being respected. I even changed the hard coded values in startGrails.bat as suggested above and still no. This finally targeted why.

Answer (score 2):

Below approach fixed the issue for me

Inside **GRAILS_HOME\bin** there's a batch file named **startGrails.bat**

Edit the file and change the Xmx and Xms size mentioned:

```
set GRAILS_OPTS=-server -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

restart the grails.

Answer (score 0):

Also to much (little) dynamic groovy code in grails app (inside of domain sub method) can decrease free heap size. After corrected dynamic/indirect code into local variable on each statement, a heap problem vanished.